# How can I type select an interface on a pointer-to-pointer in Go?

Tags: pointers, types, interface, casting, go

I have a pair of interfaces defined like so:

```
type Marshaler interface {
    Marshal() ([]byte, error)
}

type Unmarshaler interface {
    Unmarshal([]byte) error
}
```

I have a simple type which implement these:

```
type Foo struct{}

func (f *Foo) Marshal() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(f)
}

func (f *Foo) Unmarshal(data []byte) error {
    return json.Unmarshal(data, &f)
}
```

I am using a library which defines a different interface, and implementing it like so:

```
func FromDb(target interface{}) { ... }
```

The value being passed for `target` is a pointer to pointer:

```
fmt.Println("%T\n", target) // Prints **main.Foo
```

Typically this function does a type switch and then operates on the type underneath.  I would like to have common code for all types that implement my `Unmarshaler` interface but can't figure out how to get from a pointer-to-pointer of a specific type to my interface.

You cannot define methods on a pointer to a pointer:

```
func (f **Foo) Unmarshal(data []byte) error {
    return json.Unmarshal(data, f)
}
// compile error: invalid receiver type **Foo (*Foo is an unnamed type)
```

You cannot define receiver methods on pointer types:

```
type FooPtr *Foo

func (f *FooPtr) Unmarshal(data []byte) error {
    return json.Unmarshal(data, f)
}
// compile error: invalid receiver type FooPtr (FooPtr is a pointer type)
```

Casting to `Unmarshaler` doesn't work:

```
x := target.(Unmarshaler)
// panic: interface conversion: **main.Foo is not main.Unmarshaler: missing method Unmarshal
```

Casting to `*Unmarshaler` doesn't work either:

```
x := target.(*Unmarshaler)
// panic: interface conversion: interface is **main.Foo, not *main.Unmarshaler
```

How can I get from this pointer-to-pointer type to my interface type without needing to switch on every possible implementor type?

Answer (score 3):

It's ugly, but is *is* possible to have the semantic equivalent of a pointer to pointer receiver. For example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type P *int

type W struct{ p P }

func (w *W) foo() {
        fmt.Println(*w.p)
}

func main() {
        var p P = new(int)
        *p = 42
        w := W{p}
        w.foo()
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/KRryUbBqs_)

---

Output:

```
42
```

---

Note that

```
fmt.Println(*w.p)
```

above is actually

```
fmt.Println(*(*w).p)
```

where the extra work is done for you by the compiler automagically.

Answer (score 2):

If `target` is a `**Foo` and `*Foo` implements `Unmarshaler`, you can do:

```
var x Unmarshaler = *target
```

If target is a an `interface{}` containing a `**Foo`, this would work instead:

```
var x Unmarshaler = *(target.(**Foo))
```

It's a similar idea if you have a type switch.

Whenever I have to deal with pointer-to-pointer or pointer-to-reference, the variable life-time is generally pretty short and they quickly go back to being a single pointer (or plain reference) again.

I'd evaluate whether the pointer-to-pointer is indeed required for the use case at hand or whether you can do something like that.

Comment: `target` is defined in the argument list as `interface{}`, so you cannot assign it to `Unmarshaler`.  Hence the type switch.  It seems to me that a pointer-to-pointer probably isn't necessary, but that's what this library (gorp) gives me -- maybe I should try to fix the library instead.

Comment: I see.

This would work then: `var x Unmarshaler = *(target.(**Foo))`

It's not quite clear whether that's a good suggestion or not because it would depend on more details of the context.

Comment: Yep. Unfortunately that requires knowing the type up front (`**Foo`), which is what I was hoping to avoid by using an interface in the first place.  Oh well, I've worked around this in the upstream library.  Thanks for your help.